# (SQL) Private endpoint is stuck in Pending state even after it has been approved by Resource (SQL) Owner "Network resource provider denied access"

Tags: sql-server, azure, networking

### Introduction

We have in the past successfully created a Private Endpoint to access an Azure SQL Server instance in the following scenario:

- Cross-subscription (The subscription ***Subscription-A*** where the Private Endpoint is created and the subscription ***Subscription-SQL*** that owns the Azure SQL Server instance)
- Cross tenant (***Subscription-A*** and ***Subscription-SQL*** are connected to two different tenants)

To achieve this:

1. We point at the *Resource Id* of the SQL Server instance when creating the Private Enpoint and it looks like this ([see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/private-endpoint-overview?view=azuresql&tabs=separate-vnets#create-a-cross-tenant-private-endpoint)):

> /subscriptions/<Subscription-SQL-Guid>/resourceGroups/<AzureSQL-resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<AzureSQL-server-name>

2. The Owner of ***Subscription-SQL*** will then Approve the Private Endpoint request under *Security* > *Private endpoint connections* as described in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/private-endpoint-overview?view=azuresql&tabs=separate-vnets#review-and-approve-a-request-to-create-a-private-endpoint)
3. The Requester of the Private Endpoint can then see the Private Endpoint's connection status as *Approved* and the Private Endpoint may be used to communicate with the SQL Server instance.

#### Our problem is that

when we perform the exact same process from another subscription ***Subscription-B***, the Private Endpoint's connection status is stuck on "Pending" at step 3.

Step 2. *seems* to go as expected and yields *Success* to the person approving the endpoint.

#### Troubleshooting

We resorted to try and approved the private endpoint connection using Azure CLI:

```
az network private-endpoint-connection approve --resource-group "&lt;AzureSQL-resource-group-name&gt;" --name "&lt;Subscription-B-private-endpoint-name&gt;-&lt;some-guid&gt;" --type Microsoft.Sql/servers --description "Approved" --resource-name "&lt;AzureSQL-server-name&gt;" --debug
```

Which ran for 4-5 minutes before showing the following error:

```
cli.azure.cli.core.util: Response content:
cli.azure.cli.core.util:
{
    "properties": {
        "privateEndpoint": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/&lt;Subscription-B-Guid&gt;/resourceGroups/&lt;Subscription-B-resource-group-name&gt;/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/&lt;Subscription-B-private-endpoint-name&gt;
        },
        "groupIds": [
            "sqlServer"
        ],
        "privateLinkServiceConnectionState": {
            "status": "Approved",
            "description": "Approved",
            "actionsRequired": "None"
        },
        "provisioningState": "Failed"
    },
    "id": "/subscriptions/&lt;Subscription-SQL-Guid&gt;/resourceGroups/&lt;AzureSQL-resource-group-name&gt;/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/&lt;AzureSQL-server-name&gt;/privateEndpointConnections/&lt;Subscription-B-private-endpoint-name&gt;-&lt;some-guid&gt;",
    "name": "&lt;Subscription-B-private-endpoint-name&gt;-&lt;some-guid&gt;",
    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/privateEndpointConnections"
}
cli.azure.cli.command_modules.network.private_link_resource_and_endpoint_connections.resource_providers: Cannot query the state of private endpoint connection. Please use `az network private-endpoint-connection show` command to check the status.
```

(**Observe** `"provisioningState": "Failed"`)

Then ran `az network private-endpoint-connection show`:

```
az network private-endpoint-connection show --resource-group "&lt;AzureSQL-resource-group-name&gt;" --name "&lt;Subscription-B-private-endpoint-name&gt;-&lt;some-guid&gt;" --type Microsoft.Sql/servers --resource-name "&lt;AzureSQL-server-name&gt;" --debug
```

Which yielded the following:

```
cli.azure.cli.core.util: Response content:
cli.azure.cli.core.util:
{
    "properties": {
        "privateEndpoint": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/&lt;Subscription-B-Guid&gt;/resourceGroups/&lt;Subscription-B-resource-group-name&gt;/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/&lt;Subscription-B-private-endpoint-name&gt;"
        },
        "groupIds": [
            "sqlServer"
        ],
        "privateLinkServiceConnectionState": {
            "status": "Approved",
            "description": "Approved",
            "actionsRequired": "None"
        },
        "provisioningState": "Failed"
    },
    "id": "/subscriptions/&lt;Subscription-SQL-Guid&gt;/resourceGroups/&lt;AzureSQL-resource-group-name&gt;/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/&lt;AzureSQL-resource-group-name&gt;/privateEndpointConnections/&lt;Subscription-B-private-endpoint-name&gt;-&lt;some-guid&gt;",
    "name": "&lt;Subscription-B-private-endpoint-name&gt;-&lt;some-guid&gt;",
    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/privateEndpointConnections"
}
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnFilterResult []
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/&lt;Subscription-SQL-Guid&gt;/resourceGroups/&lt;AzureSQL-resource-group-name&gt;/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/&lt;AzureSQL-resource-group-name&gt;/privateEndpointConnections/&lt;Subscription-B-private-endpoint-name&gt;-&lt;some-guid&gt;",
  "name": "&lt;Subscription-B-private-endpoint-name&gt;-&lt;some-guid&gt;",
  "properties": {
    "groupIds": [
      "sqlServer"
    ],
    "privateEndpoint": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/&lt;Subscription-B-Guid&gt;/resourceGroups/&lt;Subscription-B-resource-group-name&gt;/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/&lt;Subscription-B-private-endpoint-name&gt;",
      "resourceGroup": "&lt;Subscription-B-resource-group-name&gt;"
    },
    "privateLinkServiceConnectionState": {
      "actionsRequired": "None",
      "description": "Approved",
      "status": "Approved"
    },
    "provisioningState": "Failed"
  },
  "resourceGroup": "&lt;AzureSQL-resource-group-name&gt;",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/privateEndpointConnections"
}
```

Which gives the same `"provisioningState": "Failed"` but no more.

After that we realised that an error message would appear in the event logger in the Azure portal 4-5 minuters after approving the endpoint (whether this was done via the GUI or the CLI).

#### Azure/Microsoft support

We had a support ticket opened with Microsoft Support for one and a half month to no avail.
We have had to reproduce the issue and send logs several times and they would pretend to check internally but always coming back with the same ludicrous suggestion that the problem was that the SQL Owner lacked permissions to the Private Endpoint.
The SQL Owner should not need permissions to the Private Endpoint and it is even impossible to achieve in a cross-tenant cross-subscription scenario (hence the possibility to create a Private Endpoint using only the Resource ID).

In the end we got the following error message from the support:
`Network resource provider denied access: '%ls'`
Which, to date, yields 3 results in Google search (none of them explaining what the error means)

Answer (score 0):

**TL:DR;** You need to register the `Microsoft.Sql` resource provider on the subscription that is creating the Private Endpoint (as well as `Microsoft.Network`)

We compared our subscription and finally found out that we needed to Register the `Microsoft.Sql` resource provider on ***Subscription-B*** ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types))

This is something that can even be found [in the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/rbac-permissions):

> Microsoft.Network and the specific resource provider you are deploying, for example Microsoft.Sql,  must be registered at the subscription level

The lack of feedback in the Azure portal is likely a bug